# Force page to open in new window selenium-web-driver python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

How do i force a link to open in new window in selenium-web-driver python and switch to it extract data and close it
currently i am using following code

```
for tag in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//body//a[@href]'):
            href = str(tag.get_attribute('href'))
            print href
            if not href:
                continue
            window_before = self.driver.window_handles[0]
            print window_before
            ActionChains(self.driver) \
                .key_down(Keys.CONTROL ) \
                .click(tag) \
                .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
                .perform()
            time.sleep(10)
            window_after = self.driver.window_handles[-1]
            self.driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
            print window_after
            time.sleep(10)
            func_url=self.driver.current_url
            self.driver.close()
            self.driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
```

**problem**

1. the above code does not force if it hits a link with

   `<a href="" target="_blank">something</a>`
2. after going through some two links it stales printing

   > StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below approach to open link in new window:

```
current_window = self.driver.current_window_handle
link = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
href = link.get_attribute('href')
if href:
    self.driver.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0]);', href)
else:
    link.click()
new_window = [window for window in self.driver.window_handles if window != current_window][0]
self.driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
# Execute required operations
self.driver.close()
self.driver.switch_to.window(current_window)
```

This should allow you to get link `URL` and open it in new window with `JavaScriptExecutor` if it's not empty string and just click the link otherwise. As problematic link has attribute `target="_blank"` it will be opened in new window

Comment: works like charm forces everything to new window thanks mate